# Uglify can't parse "flow.js"

Tags: bower, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-uglify, angular-fullstack, ng-flow

I'm having an annoying issue where uglify (called through grunt-usemin) cannot parse the url for a package named flow.js. This package is installed as a dependency of ng-flow.

The url looks like this:

```
bower_components/flow.js/dist/flow.js
```

When I run grunt build, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Unable to read "dist/public/bower_components/flow.js" file (Error code: EISDIR). Use --force to continue.
```

Since I don't know much about usemin and uglify, I can't put my finger on the issue. My guess was that it breaks when it gets at the first "flow.js" of the url. So, I tried to install flow.js as flowjs in my bower.json, but since its a dependency of ng-flow it will still get flow.js when running bower update.

Can anyone tell me more about this error, or suggest me a workaround to rename the dependency package?

Edit: usemin part of the Gruntfile

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html'],
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public'
  }
},
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/**/*.js'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
    ],
    // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
    patterns: {
      js: [
        [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
      ]
    }
  }
}
grunt.registerTask('build', [
'clean:dist',
'injector:less', 
'concurrent:dist',
'injector',
'wiredep',
'useminPrepare',
'autoprefixer',
'ngtemplates',
'concat',
'ngAnnotate',
'copy:dist',
'cdnify',
'cssmin',
'uglify',
'rev',
'usemin']);
```

For the records, the grunt file is generated using https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Comment: What do the relevant section(s) of your Gruntfile look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Grunt can't distinguish between a directory ending in '.js' and a .js file.

The workaround will be to use a wildcard expression to grab the files in flow.js and to exclude the directory itself.

Edit: You will need to exclude flow.js from both usemin AND rev.

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js', '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/bower_components/flow.js'],
  },
  ...

rev: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/bower_components/flow.js'
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, it still tries to include the folder and crash :(. (I tried to change the order but it didnt have any effect)

Comment: YES! From now on, i shall call you Grandmaster!

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that Grunt can't distinguish between a directory ending in '.js' and a .js file.

This is a wrong statement. Grunt use `minimatch` lib to configure how to search for files, and there is a `isFile` filter that you can set to true to only search files. [See grunt.file.expand](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand)

Following [this link](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function) you will find an example with `filter: 'isFile'`.

By the way you should upgrade to usemin v3, as this issue seems to be solved as you can see in [issue #474](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/474)

You can see my patch [here](https://github.com/ArturT/rubygems-tracker/pull/1) where I've migrate the project to usemin 3 and switch grunt-rev to grunt-filerev.

Comment: Thank you for this info, I pointed this out to the guys over at angular-fullstack!